# Images in grid view load slowly android

Tags: android, performance, gridview

I want to diplay approx 50 images in gridview control of android. All images are stored in drawable folder of android studio. When I run application it will hang up little bit and not load very smoothly, So I had tried some caching technique still I did not get much improvement in performance. Can any one help me to found best solution to load large amount of images in gridview of android.

Comment: use any image loading library like glide, picaso or universal image loader.

Comment: Also try to implement pagination.